# Android - Why won't my Toast message show?

Tags: java, android, toast

My toast doesn't show up and I am confused because I think I made it correctly, I don't understand.  As you can see its a program that shows three buttons, the first one activates a download which is supposed to open the PDFs file automatically - if there is no pdf reader a toast should pop up saying there isn't a reader.  the other buttons take to a new screen and operate as a back button.

```
public class myactivity extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(myactivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please be patient, file downloading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    Button Section = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Section);
    Section.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent Section = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    Section.class);
            startActivity(Section);

        }
    });

    Button Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Back);
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });

    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
    downloadFile
            .execute("http://www.website.com/document.pdf");

}

class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            connection.connect();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            int tickSize = 2 * fileLength / 100;
            int nextProgress = tickSize;

            Log.d(

            "ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + fileLength);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Android/Data/"
                    + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/files";
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "test1.pdf");

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                if (total >= nextProgress) {
                    nextProgress = (int) ((total / tickSize + 1) * tickSize);
                    this.publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                }
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            showPdf();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

}

private void showPdf() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/Data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/files/test1.pdf");
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(myactivity .this,
                "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(myactivity .this,
                "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The above code show toast only if you have not declared the activity in your manifeast file but not when the pdf is not present. You must use `FileNotFoundException` for your requirement.

Updated:::

```
try{
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/Data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/files/test1.pdf");
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(myactivity .this,
                "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(myactivity .this,
                "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: I should always have the file there, so if I change to FileNotFound it will just see the file and not display the toast regardless of if there is a pdf reader installed correct?

Comment: Trying to replace 'ActivityNotFoundException' with 'FileNotFoundException' gives this error: "Unreachable catch block for 'FileNotFoundException'. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

Comment: Thanks for the update, but on the line for the FileNotFoundException eclipse is still throwing an error.  the error states "Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body" It's option is to remove the catch clause?

Comment: instead try catch(Exception e){} to catch all type of exceptions

Comment: with (Exception e) the code is good with eclipse but nothing happens.  I get no Toast message. Confused...

Comment: Thank you Argarwal, the PostExecute was the correct way to fix this.